How to read a feed that provides no GUID, but avoid false positives and false negatives of duplicates?
We receive alerts from a RSS feed. It contains a title, message, and pub date. For whatever reason, the organization that provides the system for creating the alerts did not include it creating a GUID, and does not seem inclined to do so.
The result was that alerts were being missed because The folks that type the alerts in often use the same title, and the title is what gets used for the GUID in the absence of one.
Right now we're using Aggregator.
One issues is that there doesn't seem to be any hook published by Aggregator that would allow access to the raw feed values, including pubdate. I wrote a pre save hook that takes the title and appends the feed item's timestamp to it. This created a truly unique GUID but swung the pendulum all the way to the other side: If I don't touch the GUID and let it use the title, it assumes duplicates when the messages are not, a false positive.
But if I make a unique GUID in the hook, nothing is ever a duplicate, even when it should be….a false negative.
Cron runs every minute and it saved the same messages over and over with each having a different constructed GUID.
I'm guessing the decision whether to create the Aggregator item is downstream from the hook.
Would Feeds handle this differently? Another option would be to compare the title and message to stored items.

Instead of asking for "the best," say "How can I do XYZ?"  Then you can pick the answer you think is the best, but you can't ask for "the best" in the question.  This is just how Stack Exchange network sites work.  Also, this question is missing important details, such as what does the RSS feed contain?  In Feeds, you need to set at least one "unique" field (usually the GUID, but could be something else) or you will get duplicates.  However, you can use Tamper to create a custom plugin to generate the GUID from the input (which is why the question should include the input).

For each feed, the values to be imported are mapped to Drupal fields.  So with the Feeds module, you will get access to the title, mesage, and pub date in the UI (assuming that the entity that you are importing the feed to has these fields).
The Feeds module uses the concept of Unique fields to prevent duplicates.
Unique fields are set per feed type at /admin/structure/feeds/manage/my-feed/mapping.
If no Unique field is set, every time the feed is imported, an entity will be created for every data item.  This is not what you want.
So you need to set a unique field.  If the message or pub date is unique, just set that as Unique and you're done.
If the requirement for what is unique is more complex, you can configure multiple unique fields in the Mapping UI to try to get the correct combination that eliminates duplicates, or you can use the Feeds Tamper module to write a small custom plugin that generates a value that prevents duplicates as you desire.  (Feeds Tamper also includes some built-in plugins that may get the job done.)

Thank you, @Patrick Kenny
