How to prevent sitewide alert from ingesting duplicates?
I'm using:
Drupal: 10.2.4
feeds: 3.0-rc2
feeds_tamper: 2.x-dev
sitewide_alert: 2.x-dev
Processor Settings is set for the feed to Update existing sitewide alerts.
Feeds Tamper is set to create a GUID (the feed doesn't contain one) as
Channel 1-<title>-<timestamp>

so
Channel 1-My Title - 10/17/24-1729208414

where the "My Title - 10/17/24" is from the item's title, then prepended and appended values as I defined.
I hook my_module_sitewide_alert_presave and set the schedule start and end date values.
If I run the import twice, I get two of the same alerts, as follows:
sitewide_alert__feeds_item
    ----------------------+----------------------------------+
    | bundle         | deleted | entity_id | revision_id | langcode | delta | feeds_item_target_id | feeds_item_imported | feeds_item_url | feeds_item_guid                           | feeds_item_hash                  |
    +----------------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+----------------------+---------------------+----------------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
    | sitewide_alert |       0 |        32 |          32 | en       |     0 |                    2 |          1729631534 | NULL           | Channel 1-Alert - 10/17/24-1729208414 | 67d043159b6e9847df5e7868a1813cff |
    | sitewide_alert |       0 |        33 |          33 | en       |     0 |                    2 |          1729631587 | NULL           | Channel 1-Alert - 10/17/24-1729208414 | 67d043159b6e9847df5e7868a1813cff |

sitewide_alert_field_data

| id | vid | langcode | status | user_id | name             | style   | dismissible | dismissible_ignore_before_time | limit_to_pages | limit_to_pages_negate | message__value                       | message__format | scheduled_alert | scheduled_date__value | scheduled_date__end_value | created    | changed    | revision_translation_affected | default_langcode |
+----+-----+----------+--------+---------+------------------+---------+-------------+--------------------------------+----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------------------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+------------------+
| 52 |  52 | en       |      1 |       1 | Alert - 10/17/24 | primary |           1 |                              0 | NULL           |                     0 | The main elevator is out of service. | plain_text      |               0 | NULL                  | NULL                      | 1729675408 | 1729675408 |                             1 |                1 |
| 53 |  53 | en       |      1 |       1 | Alert - 10/17/24 | primary |           1 |                              0 | NULL           |                     0 | The main elevator is out of service. | plain_text      |               0 | NULL                  | NULL                      | 1729675446 | 1729675446 |                             1 |                1 |

The feed type definition:
SETTINGS
Fetcher: downloaded from URL
Parser: RSS/Atom
Downloaded: Every 1 hour

FETCHER
Nothing selected

PROCESSOR
Insert New Sitewide Alerts
Update Existing Sitewide Alerts
Previously Imported Items: Keep
Expire Sitewide Alerts: Never
Owner: admin (1)

Feed log settings all enabled as shown in the screen capture, and the db has entries for feeds_import_log_entry, but no log files are actually created and no errors (permissions, etc.) thrown.
The timestamp in the tamper is the token provided, which is the timestamp at which the source feed item was created, which is identical each time, of course, since it's the same source item.
Here is the presave hook:
function my_module_sitewide_alert_presave(EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->get('scheduled_alert') == NULL) {
    $entity->set('scheduled_alert', TRUE);
  }
  if ($entity->get('scheduled_date') == NULL) {
    $date_time_input = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $date_time_input_next = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+24 Hour'));
    $start_date = new DrupalDateTime($date_time_input); // Adjust the start date and time as needed.
    $end_date = new DrupalDateTime($date_time_input_next);
    $entity->set('scheduled_date', [
      'value' => $start_date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'),
      'end_value' => $end_date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'),
    ]);
  }
}

Why is the duplicate (in terms of the GUID) being added? Is it not recognizing that the items are identical, or is it inserting when they are instead of updating?

What time does the timestamp represent? Why can’t we see your custom code?

We also need to see the feed type definition.

Feeds has a logging submodule; enable that and it should give you a big hint why you are getting duplicates.

I've added the additional information, above, including the code, and an answer re the timestamp and the logging submodule (which seems impaired).

Which ID in the feed did you set as unique? You didn’t say.

Is that a setting somewhere? I set a tamper to make the GUID field value unique in the sitewide alert, assuming it was what needed to be (and because the GUID tag in the feed is always empty). There isn’t anything unique in the source feed without the tamper. I’m assuming by the behavior that it thinks the record is always unique for some reason, rather than identical?

@monalisa That was it. Ugh, I'm so blind. I didn't even notice the 'unique' column in the mappings. As soon as I checked the box for the GUID field, the problem was resolved. Please note that in an answer so I can select it, and thank you!!

I don't think the question deserves a downvote. It was very clear, informative, and missing something doesn't make the question a bad one.

I didn't downvote it but ultimately the question should be about Feeds and that's how it should be posed. The use-case details are useful and should remain but it should be centered around Feeds.

I agree…but that would imply that I have to begin by knowing that of the 3 players, feeds, tamper, and sitewide alerts that feeds is the issue, which I didn’t. Whether Drupal, cars or medicine, the symptom being asked about can end up being far removed from the cause. I think some folks are too quick to down vote.

This is the same as https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/320905/how-to-read-a-feed-that-provides-no-guid-but-avoid-false-positives-and-false-ne

With feeds it is necessary to designate a column as unique for it to act in the way you want with the GUID.
